# What is this 3rd person game with medieval-style battles?

Tags: game-identification

The game is shown [in this video](https://youtu.be/t1lxVgyKSmc?list=PLZDBsCo_UDNm6BPK98EXK0taK4oRsy3jO&t=364), for example, from 6:04 to approximately 7:40.

[image: Knights battling 1]

[image: Knights battling 2]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [*For Honor*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/304390/FOR_HONOR/), a game released in February 2017. Could be kinda easily mistaken for Chivalry, but there are some distinct differences (e.g. Chivalry doesn't have NPCs that actively participate in combat and fight, combat system is a bit different, etc.).

Comment: So it just took some extra time reading comments on this video to find the name.

Answer (score -7):

This is -
Chivalry: Medieval Warfare

https://store.steampowered.com/app/219640/Chivalry_Medieval_Warfare/

Comment: Wow. This game changed *a lot* since the last time I have launched it. Which gamemode/DLC is that? Or is it the core game now?

Comment: Turns out like it's not Chivalry, it's *For Honor*

Comment: yes sorry it looks very similar